# send data from ajax to php

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
  <script>
      var er ="hi";

      $( "#save" ).click(function() {
      var er = $('#edit').val();
      alert(er);

    });

 $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 's.php', 
    data: { er:er},
    success: function(response) {
        alert(er);
                                }
            });
  </script>
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

You must write the ajax code in click function, otherwise ajax code will execute on page load.

```
var er ="hi";

$( "#save" ).click(function() {
   var er = $('#edit').val();
   alert(er);
   $.ajax({  
     type: 'POST',  
     url: 's.php', 
     data: {'er':er},
     success: function(response) {
        alert(er);
     }
   });
});
```

Try above code. it will work for you.

Comment: I also would add quotes to `er` as in `{ "er" : er }` as in this case `er` is a variable